# Error in simple todo demo code of Simperium for android

Tags: android, simperium

I downloaded the [demo code](https://github.com/Simperium/simpletodo-android).

After running the code :

[image: Screenshot]

I am getting this screen.  I signed in with same username and id on other device, but nothing is happening.

On entering text, I'm getting the following error :

```
11-30 18:29:58.731  14566-16417/com.simperium.simpletodo E/SQLiteDatabase﹕ Error inserting bucketName=todo changeVersion=
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: changeVersions.bucketName (code 2067)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:780)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1471)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1341)
            at com.simperium.android.GhostStore.setChangeVersion(GhostStore.java:98)
            at com.simperium.client.Bucket.setChangeVersion(Bucket.java:416)
            at com.simperium.client.Bucket.indexComplete(Bucket.java:411)
            at com.simperium.client.Channel$IndexProcessor.notifyDone(Channel.java:1126)
            at com.simperium.client.Channel$IndexProcessor.next(Channel.java:1039)
            at com.simperium.client.Channel$IndexProcessor.addIndexPage(Channel.java:1107)
            at com.simperium.client.Channel$IndexProcessor.start(Channel.java:994)
            at com.simperium.client.Channel.updateIndex(Channel.java:397)
            at com.simperium.client.Channel.access$100(Channel.java:38)
            at com.simperium.client.Channel$2.execute(Channel.java:187)
            at com.simperium.client.Channel$CommandInvoker.executeCommand(Channel.java:743)
            at com.simperium.client.Channel.executeCommand(Channel.java:713)
            at com.simperium.client.Channel.receiveMessage(Channel.java:667)
            at com.simperium.android.WebSocketManager.onMessage(WebSocketManager.java:420)
            at com.simperium.android.WebSocketManager$2.onMessage(WebSocketManager.java:211)
            at com.simperium.android.AsyncWebSocketProvider$1$2.onStringAvailable(AsyncWebSocketProvider.java:85)
            at com.koushikdutta.async.http.WebSocketImpl$1.onMessage(WebSocketImpl.java:88)
            at com.koushikdutta.async.http.HybiParser.emitFrame(HybiParser.java:420)
            at com.koushikdutta.async.http.HybiParser.access$800(HybiParser.java:46)
            at com.koushikdutta.async.http.HybiParser$5.onDataAvailable(HybiParser.java:197)
            at com.koushikdutta.async.DataEmitterReader.handlePendingData(DataEmitterReader.java:24)
            at com.koushikdutta.async.DataEmitterReader.onDataAvailable(DataEmitterReader.java:41)
            at com.koushikdutta.async.Util.emitAllData(Util.java:22)
            at com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncSSLSocketWrapper.onDataAvailable(AsyncSSLSocketWrapper.java:230)
            at com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncSSLSocketWrapper$5.onDataAvailable(AsyncSSLSocketWrapper.java:217)
            at com.koushikdutta.async.Util.emitAllData(Util.java:22)
            at com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncNetworkSocket.onReadable(AsyncNetworkSocket.java:146)
            at com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncServer.runLoop(AsyncServer.java:788)
            at com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncServer.run(AsyncServer.java:626)
            at com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncServer.access$700(AsyncServer.java:41)
            at com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncServer$13.run(AsyncServer.java:568)
```

Please help if anyone knows about it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The demo app relies on the soft keyboard to add new items, so make sure to have it enabled in your emulator or device.

I'll research the sql error, but it appears to only show in the emulator log and not on a real device.

Comment: yea on device i am able to write text from keyboard.

Comment: Then if you tap on 'Add' on the keyboard does it create a ToDo? Might need to use the default Google keyboard.

Comment: yea TODO bucket is added on simperium server but its empty.Yea i am using only default keyboard

Comment: Can you pull the latest changes from GitHub for the ToDo app? I added an 'Add' button next to the text area so that you don't need to rely on the IME action.

https://github.com/Simperium/simpletodo-android

Comment: Yes,This is working fine.Thanks alot!!! can you please tell how can i integrate this code into my already working app to send bulk amount of Data in JSon form.?

Answer (score 0):

The error states:

```
UNIQUE constraint failed: changeVersions.bucketName
```

`bucketName` has a UNIQUE constraint, which means that each new inserted value has to be unique.

So you tried to insert an object with a bucketName which already existed in the database.

If you think you can have multiple objects with the same bucketName, remove the constraint.

If you shouldn't, check before inserting if there's already one, and handle it gracefully.

Comment: i am trying to enter different text everytime.Also tried with different bucket name. Same result